# Loading modules that change sys.path

Tags: python

Say that in Python I load a module that changes the `sys.path`. Would that change the loader's `sys.path` as well? If it does, is there any way to make sure that I can *restore* it later?

And what about the opposite scenario? Say the *loader* makes a change to `sys.path` before loading the module. Would the module see the regular `sys.path` (i.e. `PYTHONPATH`, etc.), or would it see the new `sys.path`?

Comment: I'd be interested in the answer to this. Have you run any code to test this out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes it will affect `sys.path` anywhere.... you can save it and restore it later

```
import sys
_opath = sys.path[:] #get a copy of whatever sys.path is at this point

#do imports

sys.path = _opath
```

you might be able to convert it to a tuple instead of a list ... depending on how they are adding to the path that may work but it might break some of your imported modules if they are changing paths

you can also access

```
os.environ["PYTHONPATH"]
```