# Module imports from relative folders with regular execution

Tags: python, python-2.7

Say I have the following structure:

```
app/
   __init__.py
   mod.py

   pkg/
      __init__.py
      submod.py
```

where the module `submod` has a relative import to `mod`, i.e.:

```
from .. import mod
```

I understand that if I want to execute `submod` as a script, I can do the following from `app/`

```
python -m pkg.submod
```

But I would like `submod.py` to be an executable module that I can call from **anywhere in the system** with

`python /path/to/submod.py`

I thought that [PEP-366](http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0366/) fixed this, i.e. I thought that adding the following boilerplate code before I do any relative imports in `submod`:

```
if __name__ == "__main__" and __package__ is None:
    __package__ = "app.pkg"
```

I could then go back to the regular `python /path/to/submod.py`. However, when I do that I get:

```
SystemError: Parent module 'app' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
```

Why?

Finally I understand that one solution is to manipulate `sys.path` in `submod` so that it can see `mod1` and then do the regular `import mod1` and avoid relative imports. **But** as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17937402/loading-modules-that-change-sys-path) shows, this is dangerous because any changes to `sys.path` in one module propagate to everything else, so in general it is not a good idea to tamper with `sys.path`.

Is there any way to have either:

- **relative imports** with support for regular **python /path/to/submod.py** calls

or

- the ability to execute my module with **python /path/to/submod.py** without having to tamper with `sys.path` or `PYTHONPATH`

?

Comment: You might want to watch out for including scripts inside a package hierarchy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18087122/python-sharing-common-code-among-a-family-of-scripts

Comment: `from .. import pkg1.mod1` isn't a valid import statement in either 2.6-7 or 3.x; it should give you a `SyntaxError` before you can even get to the problem you're trying to debug. If you change it to `from ..pkg1 import mod1`, you get an import-related `SystemError`, but not the one you're showing. It's hard to debug a problem that can't be reproduced in code that we can't see; can you give us an actual [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates your problem?

Comment: Also… which Python version are you using?

Comment: Thanks @abarnert - I just updated the OP to answer both of your questions

Comment: Are you trying to understand why this doesn't work, looking for the least hacky workaround (there are no non-hacky workarounds) to force it to work, or looking for the best way to do what you're actually trying to do?

Comment: @user815423426: There is no non-hacky way to do exactly _this_… but there's a very easy and completely non-hacky way to do what you probably really need: Split `submod.py` into the actual module, and a script that sits alongside the package that just imports the submodule and calls its "main" function.

Comment: @abarnert That's actually a great idea. Maybe you can add that to your answer? That's probably the best way to proceed.

Comment: @abarnert By the way, would `main.py` be able to import a  `submod.py` that has relative imports even though I will still **not** be adding its parents to `PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: @user815423426: OK, I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As PEP 366 explicitly says right after the boilerplate that you copied:

> Note that this boilerplate is sufficient only if the top level package is already accessible via `sys.path`. Additional code that manipulates `sys.path` would be needed in order for direct execution to work without the top level package already being importable.

So, assuming your code looks like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__" and __package__ is None:
    __package__ = "app.pkg"
from .. import mod
```

You should get an exception like this:

```
SystemError: Parent module 'app' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
```

As the error message implies, you need to get `app` imported somehow before you can do any relative imports. That obviously means you can't relative-import `app`, so you need to absolute-import it. There are various hacky ways you could do this, or you could do what the PEP suggests and munge `sys.path` with all of the problems that implies. But otherwise, you can't do this.

---

This is just one of multiple reasons that trying to run a script from the middle of a package is hard. And that's intentional; as explained in [PEP 3122](http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-3122/):

> Guido views running scripts within a package as an anti-pattern.

There are two ways to accomplish what you want. The first, you've already got working: just run the module as a module instead of a script. (And making that work is what PEP 366 was primarily for.) The other is to split the module and script into two pieces. Which you can do trivially just by writing a wrapper.

For example, let's say `submod.py` looks like this silly toy example:

```
if __name__ == "__main__" and __package__ is None:
    __package__ = "app.pkg"
from .. import mod

def main(argv):
    print(argv)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    main(sys.argv)
```

Create a new file, say, `sub.py`, as a sibling to the package:

```
import sys
import app.pkg.submod
app.pkg.submod.main(sys.argv)
```

Now, you can run `sub.py` from anywhere on the system. As [`sys.path`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.path) says:

> As initialized upon program startup, the first item of this list, path[0], is the directory containing the script that was used to invoke the Python interpreter.

Since that directory is also the directory `app` is in, you're guaranteed to be able to absolute-import `app.pkg.submod`, which means that `submod` will be able to relative-import whatever it wants.

Answer (score 1):

The package isn't `pkg2`; it's `app.pkg2`. Set `__package__` accordingly:

```
if __name__ = '__main__' and __package__ is None:
    __package__ = 'app.pkg2'
```

If that's not the problem, then `app` probably isn't on the path. The best solution I know of is to put it on the path (by moving `app` or putting its current directory in PYTHONPATH), but if you're looking for a way to let modules in `app` see each other without being visible to external modules, I don't know of anything. It seems like it could be useful.

Comment: Your posted directory structure isn't consistent with your error message.

Comment: Sorry. I typed it too fast (wasn't copying).